# How can I deal with error message when not using {{form}} in Django template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-login

I implemented `Login` and it works good except error message.

If I used `{{ form.as_p }}`, it shows error message.

```
<form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- id / pw -->
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="btn-controls">
            <div class="row">
                <input id="btn-login" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="login_submit" value="로 그 인" />
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value={{ request.GET.next}} />
                <a id="btn-fblogin" href="{% url 'social:begin' backend='facebook' %}" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12"><i class="icon-facebook"></i> 1초만에 페이스북으로 로그인 </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 control">
            <div class="signup">
                아직 차차다방 회원이 아니세요? &nbsp
                <a href="#" id="signuplink"> 가입하기 </a>
            </div>
            <div class="forget">
                <a href="#"> 비밀번호를 잊어버리셨나요? </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

But when I change template like this, it doesn't show any error when I type wrong id or pw...

```
<form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
        <input id="id_username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
        <input id="id_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="btn-controls">
            <div class="row">
                <input id="btn-login" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="login_submit" value="로 그 인" />
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value={{ request.GET.next}} />
                <a id="btn-fblogin" href="{% url 'social:begin' backend='facebook' %}" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12"><i class="icon-facebook"></i> 1초만에 페이스북으로 로그인 </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12 control">
            <div class="signup">
                아직 차차다방 회원이 아니세요? &nbsp
                <a href="#" id="signuplink"> 가입하기 </a>
            </div>
            <div class="forget">
                <a href="#"> 비밀번호를 잊어버리셨나요? </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I make it show error message even if I don't user `{{ form.xx }}` ?

Here is my `LoginView`.

```
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login as auth_login
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.views.decorators.debug import sensitive_post_parameters
from django.views.generic import FormView

from users.forms import MyUserCreationForm


class LoginView(FormView):

    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME

    # template_name is fake one.
    # This view only process POST request from users/login_signup.html
    template_name = "users/login_signup.html"

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password'))
    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Sets a test cookie to make sure the user has cookies enabled
        request.session.set_test_cookie()

        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
        # If the test cookie worked, go ahead and
        # delete it since its no longer needed
        if self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            self.request.session.delete_test_cookie()

        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)         
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.POST.get("next")
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what exactly your question is, and also don't know if it is your answer or not, but i just say it!

You **should** use your django form that you passed from view in your template  to be able to validate the form after the submission of form.

and if your concern is how to show the form properly in they way you want, it has another solution. you can represent the form in the way you want like something below:

```
{% for field in form %} 
    <div class="input-group">
        {% if field.name=="username" %}
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                <input id="id_username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username">
        {% endif %}

        {% if field.name=="password" %}
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                <input id="id_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
        {% endif %}

        {% for error in field.errors %}
               {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, you can access the error of fields via field.errors and check the name of field with field.name!